# How to pass credentials when publishing nuget package to a local server?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

I've added the credentials to `nuget.config` as follows:

```
<packageSources>
  <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  <add key="internal" value="http://internal.server/nuget" />
</packageSources>
<packageSourceCredentials>
  <internal>
    <add key="Username" value="myuser" />
    <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="mypassword" />
 </internal>
</packageSourceCredentials>
```

I can successfully browse for packages on the this internal server. The user used is the server's local administrator.

Now I'm trying to publish a package using [Nuget Deploy](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/455301f5-cc32-4261-b4da-998bd9a6a690). The command line used is:

`nuget push "C:\mypath\mydll.nupkg" -s "http://internal.server/nuget" "apikey"`

However, I'm getting the error:

> An Error occured while deploying the nuPkg file: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
>   No credentials are available in the security package

As I should be publishing as the local administrator, I should have enough permissions on the IIS server where the nuget server is hosted.

Do I need to explicitly pass the permissions within the `nupkg`?

Comment: Could you share the detailed steps about how to use NuGet Deploy to push your packages? I get "nuget.exe not found in the configuration" error no matter I put nuget.exe in or out of the project. In addition, please put /api/v2/package after the NuGet server URL which like "http://internal.server/nuget/api/v2/package".

Comment: Can you publish the package if you run the nuget push command from command line manually?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I get the same error. Anonymous access must be enabled on the server as it looks like publishing doesn't pick up the credentials in the config file.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono What's the path of the nuget.config file you updated?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I didn't pass any path. The credentials and in the config file located in `AppData\Roaming\Nuget`. It seems that the credentials are used to browse packages but not for publishing.

Comment: How do you generate the apikey? And which credential do you want to use? Username and password or apikey?  Also make sure you use the URL format mentioned by Wendy.

Comment: The ApiKey is hardcoded in the web.config on the server. I want to use username and password so I can activate windows authentication and deactivate anonymous access on the server. The URl format mentioned didn't work.

Comment: Then you can remove the "apikey" section from the command. And what's authentication type on your IIS server, NTLM or Negotiate? The error message you get is usually related to Negotiate:Kerberos.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is a problem with the NuGet package server? It seems to me that you may just have IIS configured not to allow anonymous access.

Comment: Activating anonymous access and setting write permissions to `IIS_USRS` works. However, I want to avoid using anonymous access and use just windows authentication.